# Contact form look weird on Mac Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this contact form, and the css is set up so it looks great on most browsers but on Mac Chrome it does not look right. That is ok on Chrome of Windows.

Live link- http://wallst-training.com/about/contactref.html

Any idea what is the problem.

Screenshot:

**That is right one taken from Chrome(Windows)**
[image]

**That is wrong one taken from Chrome(Mac)**

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me on Chrome + Mac.

Comment: Are you using a table or unordered lists?

Comment: Looks fine on Mac Chrome for me as well. Is the css cached? Try clearing the cache in that browser.

Comment: Can anyone please send me a screenshot from mac. I don't have mac.

Comment: set inline on the textarea the width of field. eg: `style="width:200px;"`

Comment: clear your cache after modify the layout and test again on chrome:mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is a caching issue? Try to disable caching on this page.
In Chrome you can do this way:

1. Press F12
2. click on settings icon in bottom right
3. Check "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"
4. Then reload the page.

Or you can add version to style.css like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css?v=1.0" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

Comment: Can you please send me a screenshot from mac. I don't have mac.

Comment: @arifix to solve cache issue for all users who visit this page, you can add version param to style.css defintion.